# Spring Security: Disable Login Page while session is valid

Tags: spring, security, session, authentication

I was able to successfully implement Spring Security in my application, using a custom login page. However, I want it so that, after the user logs in successfully, when he clicks the back button of the browser of his choice, it will not redirect him back to the login page, but to home page.

Note:
The logout feature works fine, that when a user successfully logs out, he will be redirected to logout success page. But when he clicks the back button, he will not be redirected to the previous page, but to the login page.

Here is the code responsible for my login-logout configuration:

```
   @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/") //I tried adding this line hoping this could help, but to no avail...
        .and()
        .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll();   
}
```

And this is my main controller:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return "home.jsp"; 
  }

  @RequestMapping("/login")
  public String login() {
    return "login.jsp";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/logout-success")
  public String logout() {
    return "logout.jsp";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion you should disable back button of browser instead of doing changes at Spring Security side. Spring security is working perfectly here as per security guidelines. You can place following javascript code in your header section of page to disable back button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```

Reference URL : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Disable-Browser-Back-Button-Functionality-using-JavaScript.aspx

Comment: Thank you for that. But the problem is, even if I disable the back button via javascript, the login page would still be accessible via url (i.e. localhost:8080/login). I know, a user does not typically type the url og a login page even after a successful login, but still. But I'll definitely consider this idea. Thanks again!